# Reledmac: paragraph footnotes in two columns

Tags: footnotes, memoir, reledmac

I am typesetting a document using the memoir package and reledmac package.
I am trying to get the footnotes in a paragraph block, but typeset in two columns (the footnotes, not the main text).
The paragraph block, I got using `Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}` and the two columns with `Xarrangement[A]{twocol}`. But it seems is not possible to get both parameters at the same time. Am I wrong?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
%\Xarrangement[A]{twocol}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
I am happy : I saw my friend \edtext{Smith}{\Afootnote{Jones C, D.}}
on Tuesday.
I am happy : I saw my friend \edtext{Smith}{\Afootnote{Jones C, D.}}
on Tuesday.
I am happy : I saw my friend \edtext{Smith}{\Afootnote{Jones C, D.}}
on Tuesday.
I am happy : I saw my friend \edtext{Smith}{\Afootnote{Jones C, D.}}
on Tuesday.
I am happy : I saw my friend \edtext{Smith}{\Afootnote{Jones C, D.}}
on Tuesday.
I am happy : I saw my friend \edtext{Smith}{\Afootnote{Jones C, D.}}
on Tuesday.
I am happy : I saw my friend \edtext{Smith}{\Afootnote{Jones C, D.}}
on Tuesday.
I am happy : I saw my friend \edtext{Smith}{\Afootnote{Jones C, D.}}
on Tuesday.
I am happy : I saw my friend \edtext{Smith}{\Afootnote{Jones C, D.}}
on Tuesday.
I am happy : I saw my friend \edtext{Smith}{\Afootnote{Jones C, D.}}
on Tuesday.
I am happy : I saw my friend \edtext{Smith}{\Afootnote{Jones C, D.}}
on Tuesday.
I am happy : I saw my friend \edtext{Smith}{\Afootnote{Jones C, D.}}
on Tuesday.
I am happy : I saw my friend \edtext{Smith}{\Afootnote{Jones C, D.}}
on Tuesday.
I am happy : I saw my friend \edtext{Smith}{\Afootnote{Jones C, D.}}
on Tuesday.
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

I would like to have the effect of the two macros at the same time

Comment: Could you add some working code (mwe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is impossible. Please open an issue on github (but I won't have time before many, many year to implement such feature).

Comment: I may lopk to the code. Do you think it will be enoigh to combine some lines fron the paragraph option and the twocolun option?

Comment: Not so easy. But the idea is here. You have to use \parafootfmt, to use `twocolfootsetup` and to make a mixt between twocolfootgroup and parafootgroup.

Comment: In any case, I will encourage you to read the paragraphe XII.5 and XII.6 of the handbook. You may also have a good knew of TeX `\insert` mechanism.

Comment: If you want to do that, I will ask you to make a fork of reledmac github repository, and then a pull request.  The new arrangment should be called `Xarrangement[A]{twocolpara}` or something like that. I prefer you propose I pull request instead of making you own version of reledmac/reledpar.

Comment: The reason is that as reledmac/reledpar is very sensitive, and in the past, there will have many "hack" of ledmac, which there incompatible betwen them. To get an uniform distribution is better for all user.

Comment: We can chat if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I understand and supportt the idea of forking.

Comment: To be clear : I mean a fork of the github repository, which code will be merge ultimatly in the main project, not a fork of reledmac with an other name.

Comment: Ps: If you do that, could you also please. 1) Do the same for three col 2. Do the same for the \footnoteX (familiar footnotes) 3. Add documentation ?

Comment: Don't worry, it was clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60234/discussion-between-maieul-and-textnik).